# Does RIOT support ethernet physical layer?

Tags: iot, riot-os

Setup:

1. Connect stm32f407vet6 and  LAN8720, connect to ethernet
2. Code is here: `https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/tree/master/examples/emcute_mqttsn`
3. `cd RIOT/examples/emcute_mqttsn`
4. `make BOARD=stm32f4discovery all flash term`
5. With `ifconfig` ,  ethernet interface info not printed. Does RIOT support ethernet physical layer? Please see log:

```
> help
2019-05-30 17:23:32,578 - INFO #  help
2019-05-30 17:23:32,581 - INFO # Command              Description
2019-05-30 17:23:32,584 - INFO # ---------------------------------------
2019-05-30 17:23:32,587 - INFO # con                  connect to MQTT broker
2019-05-30 17:23:32,592 - INFO # discon               disconnect from the current broker
2019-05-30 17:23:32,595 - INFO # pub                  publish something
2019-05-30 17:23:32,598 - INFO # sub                  subscribe topic
2019-05-30 17:23:32,603 - INFO # unsub                unsubscribe from topic
2019-05-30 17:23:32,606 - INFO # will                 register a last will
2019-05-30 17:23:32,609 - INFO # reboot               Reboot the node
2019-05-30 17:23:32,615 - INFO # ps                   Prints information about running threads.
2019-05-30 17:23:32,617 - INFO # ping6                Ping via ICMPv6
2019-05-30 17:23:32,623 - INFO # random_init          initializes the PRNG
2019-05-30 17:23:32,628 - INFO # random_get           returns 32 bit of pseudo randomness
2019-05-30 17:23:32,632 - INFO # nib                  Configure neighbor information base
2019-05-30 17:23:32,637 - INFO # ifconfig             Configure network interfaces
> ifconfig
2019-05-30 17:23:36,554 - INFO #  ifconfig
>
```

Answer (score 2):

STM32 Ethernet is supported in RIOT [since a month ago](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/pull/10633), but the board you specified ([STM32F4Discovery](https://riot-os.org/api/group__boards__stm32f4discovery.html)) does not have an Ethernet interface, and thus the module for it is not enabled.

If your setup is similar to the discovery board, creating a board file for the stm32f407vet6 based on the discovery board and the nucleo-f767zi board that has support for STM32 Ethernet. It's not a great deal of work if you know your board, and the project would certainly appreciate a [pull request](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/pulls) with whatever you come up with.